# Программа определяющая засыпание пользователя

Tags: c#, алгоритм, нейронные-сети, web-camera

Как реализовать программу, которая сможет определить, что пользователь спит (заснул)? Возможно ли это реализовать через веб-камеру например? Возможно у вас есть подходящие идеи? Спасибо

Answer (score 10):

Звук и вебка ни к чему, они ничего не дают. Можно реализовать использование мыши, например, используя функцию GetCursorPos и сравнивая значения. Если они различны -- пользователь бодр и полон сил, иначе -- выполняем что-то свое (код, надеюсь, напишете сами). Намек на вариант с клавиатурой читайте [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx). Ну, и ещё один вариант, в отличие от остальных, не фоновый -- вывод сообщения с просьбой нажать кнопку ОК.

**UPD**

Насчет заснет в постели -- то ему проще использовать радиомышь, т.к. он спит в темноте, где вебка ничего не различит. Ну, можете ещё свое устройство придумать, например, на основе маломощного лазера и фоторезистора...

**UPD2**

Да, ещё вариант с концом фильма. Т.е. если фильм не идет, скажем, минуты три, и никакого действия со стороны юзера -- хорошо, делаем свою команду, скажем, выключаем комп...

Answer (score 6):

Как вариант - написать программу, которая через промежуток времени будет просить пользователя произнести какой либо звук (слово, фразу). Если через микрофон ничего не сказали, значит юзер спит. 
Но так придется использовать какой-то движок распознавания речи, ну, или на крайняк - анализировать уровень звука в микрофоне.

Comment: А если он будет храпеть на всю квартиру?

Answer (score 5):

Мышь не двигается долго, нет набора с клавиатуры, нет запущенных полноэкранных приложений.

Comment: Не совсем то ) Предполагается, что человек заснёт не за экраном компьютера, а в постели, и скорее всего будет смотреть фильм в полноэкранном режиме )

Answer (score 5):

Ну, если принять во внимание, что во сне человек почти не двигается (в идеале), то можно обрабатывать видеоряд с вебкамеры и отлавливать момент, когда движения нет какой-то период времени.
Еще можно отслеживать нажатия клавиш на клавитуре и движение мышкой.

Answer (score 5):

Можно останавливать фильм через какой то промежуток времени после последнего нажатия клавиатуры/движения мышки. К примеру если 30 минут ничего не происходило, то делаем паузу. Если человек спит то ему это не помешает, но если человек бодр, и смотрит фильм, то это несколько усложнит процесс просмотра:) В итоге человек либо заснет, либо встанет и нажмет на "плей"

Comment: Лично мне было бы, мягко говоря, не удобно каждые полчаса вставать только лишь из-за того, что компу интересно, сплю ли я)...

Comment: Насчет того что веб-камеру не удастся использовать из за того что темно скорее всего не правильно, так как моник должен отсвечивать достаточно света для этого.

Comment: Недостаточно. Тем более, что не думаю, что у Вас моник стоит на расстоянии 30 см. от дивана) Я уже не говорю за фильм в темных тонах...

Comment: Простите, просто интересно а зачем вообще подобная функция? Нельзя ли просто выключать фильм(компьютер,монитор) после завершения фильма?

Comment: @Monteg, нас спрашивают, мы отвечаем=) Пусть даже вопрос супертупой, наше дело указать, в чем ошибка.
З.Ы. Хотя Ваше замечание вполне логично)...

Answer (score 4):

Разработай детектор храпа!!! Ну если серьезно - каждый человек индивидуален, тем более, люди имеют свойство жить в семье, держать домашних животных. То есть, проведи социологическое иследование - какие есть факторы "засыпания". Например, следующий профиль пользователя: все работает - через час уменьшаем звук на 25% (если не было событий от мыши или клавы) и далее... Только :)индикаторы будут мигать!

Answer (score 1):

Многие проигрыватели видео имеют такую функцию. Например, в моем любимом Media Player Classic: Воспроизведение -> По окончании воспроизведения -> Выключить компьютер. Если же мы не заснули, то успеем отменить выключение, ведь в фильмах ещё очень долго идут титры.

Answer (score 1):

Если не ограничиваться аппаратурой компьютера (web-камера, микрофон и т.д.), то можно предложить использовать фитнес-трекер/умные часы (или как это сейчас называется). В них есть возможность измерять пульс, а так же передавать информацию на смартфон по bluetooth.

P.S. Уже есть [вот такое](http://www.novate.ru/news/3843/) устройство)

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, я бы так делал:
Один таймер проверяет координаты мыши, и если совпадают - запускал другой таймер, который по истечении определенного времени "что-то" делал. Надеюсь, что помог.